# Problem configuring touchscreen for raspberry pi 2

Tags: pi-2, touchscreen

I recently bought a 2.8 inch touchscreen from Adafruit to use with my raspberry pi 2. I went to the website, and followed the instructions.

I used

```
sudo raspi-config
(expand filesystem)
sudo reboot
```

which worked fine, then

```
curl -SLs https://apt.adafruit.com/add-pin | sudo bash
```

which also worked fine, and then

```
sudo apt-get install -y raspberrypi-bootloader adafruit-pitft-helper raspberrypi-kernel
```

which gave me the error

```
E: There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes
```

The site then told me to use `sudo adafruit-pitft-helper -t 28c`
which gave me `sudo: adafruit-pitft-helper: command not found`.

Anyone know what im doing wrong and how to fix this?
Sorry if im messy, im really really new to this, only a few hours of experience.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `-y` with `--force-yes`

```
sudo apt-get install --force-yes raspberrypi-bootloader adafruit-pitft-helper raspberrypi-kernel
```